# Promises confusion in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, javascript

I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around the asynchronous nature of code execution on NodeJS. I have a simple function to fetch the output of `ip a` on a Linux machine and parse out the IP Subnet manually. I'd simply like to `console.log()` the IP Subnet after that's done.

I understand that NodeJS mostly runs asynchronously so I can't expect the logic to be finished before I `console.log()` the variable. I understand to concept of Callbacks to combat this problem, but I'd prefer to have access to the variable outside the logic loop. I turned to Promises, which seems like a good solution for this, but I think I'm missing something and they're not working the way I expected. Here's my code below:

```
let subnetString = '';

function getIPLinux() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const ipOutput = spawn( 'ip', ['a'] );

    ipOutput.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        String(data).split('\n').forEach( (line) => {

            if ( line.includes('inet') && line.indexOf('inet6') < 0 && line.indexOf('127.0.0.1') < 0 ) {
                const ipSubnet = line.split(' ')[5];
                const ipStringArray = ipSubnet.split('.');
                subnetString = ipStringArray[0] + '.' + ipStringArray[1] + '.' + ipStringArray[2] + '.*';
                console.log('Found subnet at end of if loop: ' + subnetString);
            }

        })
    })

    console.log('Found subnet at end of promise: ' + subnetString);
    resolve();
  })
}

getIPLinux().then( () => {
  console.log('Found subnet after then: ' + subnetString);
});
```

My output is as follows:

```
Found subnet at end of promise: 
Found subnet after then: 
Found subnet at end of if loop: 192.168.1.*
```

Only the last line logged is correct. I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around this non-blocking code execution. I'm open to other methodologies too if I'm coming at this the wrong way.

Comment: can you have multiple `subnetString`s?

Comment: @molamk No, it's just a single string.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52747777/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46289682/1048572) to get an idea on how to promisify the data stream event emitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spawn() is also async. You're using an event callback for the stdout which is good but you're resolving the promise immediately below that without waiting for the input to finish. Try

```
ipOutput.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Found subnet at end of promise: ' + subnetString);
  resolve(subnetString);
});
```

At the end of your promise.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_close

Comment: That worked! That made a little light bulb go off for me too about the order of execution. I ended up simplifying it a bit further and just put the `resolve();` after `console.log('Found subnet at end of if loop: ' + subnetString);`

Comment: For this that seems fine and unlikely to be a problem. Keep in mind though that there's no guarantee that the **data** event will only occur once and that it will contain what you want. For large output it could be called multiple times. Even if what you want is in the first call of **data**, it could run again after your promise resolves and if you're editing a variable outside the promise like you have in your question, it could change in unpredictable ways. The program you `spawn()` is still running and possibly producing output until you get that **close** event.

Comment: You're right about that. I switched back to using the ipOutput.on('close', ...) as you originally suggested.

Answer (score 1):

- You need to **`resolve`** your `Promise` from **inside** the `.on('data', (data) => { // here })` **callback**
- **Instead** of writing **`subnetString`** as a **global** variable, **pass it inside the `Promise`**. Like this `resolve(subnetString)`
- **Don't forget to `catch`** if there's any errors. For example if no valid lines have been found
- Since you're returning **only one** `subnetString` you can use `Array.find` instead of doing a `forEach` loop. It take a *"validation"* callback and returns the item or `null` if not found

---

```
const isValidLine = l => l.includes('inet') && !l.includes('inet6') && !l.includes('127.0.0.1');

const extractSubnet = l => {
  const ipStringArray = l.split(' ')[5].split('.');
  return ipStringArray[0] + '.' + ipStringArray[1] + '.' + ipStringArray[2] + '.*';
}

function getIPLinux() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const ipOutput = spawn('ip', ['a']);

    ipOutput.stdout.on('data', data => {
      const line = data.split('\n').find(isValidLine);

      // Resolve or Reject your promise here
      if (!line) {
        reject('Line not found');
      } else {
        const subnetString = extractSubnet(line);
        resolve(subnetString);
      }
    });
  });
}

getIPLinux().then(subnetString => {
  console.log('Found subnet after then: ' + subnetString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) that wasn't correctly addressed with promises.

`resolve` is synchronously called on promise construction, a promise resolves earlier than data arrives. A promise is supposed to resolve with data but it doesn't.

Considering that only single `data` should be processed, it should be:

```
function getIPLinux() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const ipOutput = spawn( 'ip', ['a'] );

   const handler = (data) => {
        String(data).split('\n').forEach((line) => {
            if (line.includes('inet') && line.indexOf('inet6') < 0 && line.indexOf('127.0.0.1') < 0) {
                const ipSubnet = line.split(' ')[5];
                const ipStringArray = ipSubnet.split('.');
                const subnetString = ipStringArray[0] + '.' + ipStringArray[1] + '.' + ipStringArray[2] + '.*';
                ipOutput.stdout.off('data', handler);
                resolve(subnetString);
            }
        })
    })

    ipOutput.stdout.on('data', handler);
  })
}
```